# Is anyone held responsible if a VPN/proxy that doesn't log is used for illegal purposes?

Tags: vpn, proxy, legal

How do [the anonymous VPN services](https://torrentfreak.com/vpn-anonymous-review-160220/) work? It’s my understanding that if an internet connection is misused for something (such as downloading copyright material or hacking a network etc) then the person who is registered to use the IP address is held responsible, even if it wasn’t him. This is why it’s important to secure your network.

I mean if I owned two computers and set one up as a proxy server that didn’t log and used it to do a bunch of illegal stuff, if the authorities got involved would it be a valid defense that the proxy server has no logs so they can’t press any charges on me? This seems to be how the anonymous VPN services work. I mean, what happens to them if their network was used to hack something, does the service provider get charged with the crime?

Comment: Usually they work by being in a different jurisdiction, or by being run by the NSA undercover in the first place :-). In other jurisdictions yes, they might be deemed accessory to the crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, that would not be a valid defense.

Let's say you penetrate a site. The site views your IP and reports you to the authorities. They then ask your ISP who had that IP at that time, and will be directed to you. That's a lot of evidence to suggest that someone from your home and/or network hacked the site. Saying it wasn't you because your local proxy doesn't keep logs is like saying you can't have done it because you cleared your history.

The anonymous VPN services are often hosted offshore, out of reach of the authorities, and not in the same network as the attacker. :P

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot of the country where the server is and the jurisdiction there. But even in a country that would follow such cases it depends on the acual law itself. For example you mostly have to have a certain standard of security for you services. If you can prove that you have the usual security standard you won´t get punished (anonymous VPN does not mean that you can do anything, there are possibilities of black/whitelisting, denial of certain ports, protocols and stuff on the proxy). If you have a gross mistake you might. And if you set up a proxy that is reachable from the internet you are offering such a public service.

If you have the proxy only in your local network it is no proxy as your connection will go from there on to your ISP and it is still your connection... So you don´t have a proxy at all. It is not clear what your second part of the question describes.

So for your case it can´t be said as it is not clear what jurisdiction you have and what you are actually up to.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the "youtube" excuse.

To many users, to much content, impossible to manage,

Heres our disclaimer of our lack of control of data, we exempt ourselves from resposibility,
Then look official, with complaint departments etc.

To better clarify though; 2 points are needed.
 1. nature of crime.
 2. Country of server

Its all about perception, mostly.

Comment: The police is unlikely to accept this excuse. If you can't log data, you shouldn't be running a proxy service